# Pass cell value from html table to another page

Tags: php, html, web

I have form1.php and preview.php files.In form1.php file,i have an html table which contains data from database.In every row,i have a column called "Preview" and there is an icon inside the cell.When the user clicks the icon,i want to redirect to preview.php and based on rowID,i will build a query and fill the form with extra data.Any ideas?

In form1.php file:

```
<script>
function GetValue()
{

    var X = document.getElementById("myTable").rows[x.rowIndex].cells[5].innerHTML;

 }
</script>
```

With alert() function i test the above script and it's working( eg. X = 3 ).How can i pass this variable into preview.php and create an if statement based on this variable?I tried $_SESSION variables but i couldnt find a solution.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `$_GET[rowid]` to get valu through URL

```
<script>
function GetValue()
{

    var X = document.getElementById("myTable").rows[x.rowIndex].cells[5].innerHTML;
 window.location="./prerview.php?rowid="+X;

 }
</script>
```

in preview.php

use `$_GET[rowid]` to get row value from form1.php

eg

```
<?php
echo $_GET[rowid];//it will print value passed from form1.php
?>
```

Comment: I created the following script in form1.php file:  <script>
function GetValue()
{

    var X = document.getElementById("myTable").rows[x.rowIndex].cells[5].innerHTML;
  window.location="../preview.php?rowid=" + X;

 }
</script> but when i redirect to preview.php the url is: http://localhost/preview.php , not http://localhost/preview.php?rowid = 5

Comment: sorry change k to X

Comment: I changed.. But the url is "localhost/preview.php " .... I expect the url to be "localhost/preview.php?rowid = 5" , right?

Comment: try `windows.location.href=."preview.php?rowid="+X`;

Comment: Nothing happened...I want to see the variable rowid in  url when i redirect to preview.php.Later i will check how to fetch this variable

Comment: you didn't get value of rowid in url? it might be due to value in table cell check it whether value is fetched or not

Comment: <script>
function GetValue()
{

  window.location.href= 'preview.php?rowid=' + 5;

 }
</script>

Comment: waht  do you get?

Comment: This script is working fine..I have onclick="GetValue() in table row,so when i click everywhere in row i redirect with this url : "http://localhost/preview.php?rowid=5" . But when i add the var X it doesn't working and its not redirecting...I need to get cell value as text or something like that in order to pass it...

Comment: have you checked that X is picking the correct value?P.S pass this  `GetValue(this)` in onclick event .what is x.rowindex?

Comment: <script>
function GetValue(x)
{

  alert(document.getElementById("statementsTable").rows[x.rowIndex].cells[5].innerHTML);

 }
</script>

Comment: what do you get? check console

Comment: This is working fine...The alert message indicates me the id (eg. Localhost says: 3) if i click on 3rd row

Comment: then it should be assigning value to rowid in URL

Comment: <script>
function GetValue(x)
{

  alert(document.getElementById("statementsTable").rows[x.rowIndex].cells[5].innerHTML);
  window.location.href="preview.php?rowid="+document.getElementById("statementsTable").rows[x.rowIndex].cells[5].innerHTML;

 }
</script>